# android specific writing in File

Tags: java, android, file

I want to have an internal File like stock features with these properties:

File has a Maximum of `LineNumber` i.e.: 400.
New line appends to file until this limitation is reached; then, firstly removes the First Line and then appends New Line.
To remove a line it shouldn't be necessary to read and rewrite the whole file.
Is it possible to do it so?

Many thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

You need a circular file buffer. There is nothing built into Android, but you can use [This implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CircularByteBuffer.htm) which I have used in the past and works well for me.

Comment: @greqEnnin  I believe there isn't any impossible in world :) thanks for vote down;)

Comment: What are you referring to? I did not vote you down. I tried to answer your question. It is most certainly possible. Did you get the link I posted? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CircularByteBuffer.htm

Comment: this is great helpful answer but maybe find the best answer thanks for your answer bro :)